# Can't run SQL query in Visual Studio, but works in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, dapper

I basically generated a query inside a stringbuilder object which looks exactly like this:

**SQL_Insert**

```
INSERT INTO S1589_XML_Ptdes(ID, VALID_FROM_DATE, VALID_TO_DATE, SYMBOLIC_NAME, SHORT_NAME_FRENCH, SHORT_NAME_DUTCH, LONG_NAME_FRENCH, LONG_NAME_DUTCH, PTCAR_ID, DISTANCE_FROM_PTCAR, TYPE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
WITH S1589_XML_Ptdes AS (
select '142','1996-06-02','2006-05-31','111001','Quais','Perrons','Quais Gand St Pierre','Perrons Gent St Pieters','455','0','2','2010-06-04T06:21:35' from dual 
union all select '142','2006-06-01','2010-02-10','111001','Quais','Perrons','Quais Gand St Pierre','Perrons Gent St Pieters','455','-38','2','2010-06-04T06:21:35' from dual 
union all select '142','2010-02-11','2011-04-20','111001','Gand St. P','Gent St.P','Gand-Saint-Pierre','Gent-Sint-Pieters','455','-38','2','2011-04-26T09:08:00' from dual 
union all select '142','2011-04-21','2014-01-19','111001','Gent St.P','Gent St.P','Gent-Sint-Pieters','Gent-Sint-Pieters','455','-38','2','2014-01-20T14:06:39' from dual 
union all select '142','2014-01-20','2015-12-17','111001','Gent St.P','Gent St.P','Gent-Sint-Pieters','Gent-Sint-Pieters','455','0','2','2015-12-16T18:10:31' from dual 
) SELECT * FROM S1589_XML_Ptdes; COMMIT;
```

But when I run the following line: `return con.Execute(SQL_Insert.ToString());` I get the following error:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-00933: SQL
>   command not properly ended'

When I execute this query in Oracle SQL Developer, it'll insert all 5 rows and commit perfectly, no error messages or whatsoever.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing here?

I'm using Dapper as an ORM, in case that could be useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need the sub-query factoring clause and Oracle will not accept two commands (in this case, `INSERT` and `COMMIT`) in the same statement. SQL Developer will process them as two separate statements: an `INSERT` statement followed by a `COMMIT` statement.

So, remove the `COMMIT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO S1589_XML_Ptdes(ID, VALID_FROM_DATE, VALID_TO_DATE, SYMBOLIC_NAME, SHORT_NAME_FRENCH, SHORT_NAME_DUTCH, LONG_NAME_FRENCH, LONG_NAME_DUTCH, PTCAR_ID, DISTANCE_FROM_PTCAR, TYPE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
  select '142', DATE '1996-06-02', DATE '2006-05-31','111001','Quais','Perrons','Quais Gand St Pierre','Perrons Gent St Pieters','455','0','2', TIMESTAMP '2010-06-04 06:21:35' from dual union all
  select '142', DATE '2006-06-01', DATE '2010-02-10','111001','Quais','Perrons','Quais Gand St Pierre','Perrons Gent St Pieters','455','-38','2', TIMESTAMP '2010-06-04 06:21:35' from dual union all
  select '142', DATE '2010-02-11', DATE '2011-04-20','111001','Gand St. P','Gent St.P','Gand-Saint-Pierre','Gent-Sint-Pieters','455','-38','2', TIMESTAMP '2011-04-26 09:08:00' from dual union all
  select '142', DATE '2011-04-21', DATE '2014-01-19','111001','Gent St.P','Gent St.P','Gent-Sint-Pieters','Gent-Sint-Pieters','455','-38','2', TIMESTAMP '2014-01-20 14:06:39' from dual union all
  select '142', DATE '2014-01-20', DATE '2015-12-17','111001','Gent St.P','Gent St.P','Gent-Sint-Pieters','Gent-Sint-Pieters','455','0','2', TIMESTAMP '2015-12-16 18:10:31' from dual;
```

If your c# connection is not set to auto-commit then you may need to issue an explicit commit.

Also, if you are inserting `DATE` values then you should use a `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP` literal and you should review whether inserting numbers as strings is appropriate.

Comment: Leaving the commit out solved the issue. Also good to know Oracle doesn't accept two commands in the same statement. Helps alot!

Comment: Regarding the date and numbers, I'm gonna leave them as varchars since they are only used for displaying purposes

Comment: @JorisDecraecker It is usually better (unless there are significant business reasons not to do so) to pick the correct data-type for your data - even if it is just being used for display purposes.